# django admin : TclError : Can't find a usable init.tcl

Tags: python, django

I use django, python 2.7, virtualenv

I try in the admin to open a file with a dialogbox

```
def import_csv(self, request, queryset):
    import csv
    from Tkinter import *
    from tkFileDialog import *

    fileName = askopenfilename()
```

I have the error :

Can't find a usable init.tcl in the following directories: 
    C:/Python27/lib/tcl8.5 C:/mat4/env/lib/tcl8.5 C:/mat4/lib/tcl8.5 C:/mat4/env/library C:/mat4/library C:/mat4/tcl8.5.2/library C:/tcl8.5.2/library

This probably means that Tcl wasn't installed properly.

I tried to use easygui but it is the same

How to fix this error ?

Answer (score 4):

This can't possibly work. Django is a web framework. You can't run a desktop GUI like Tkinter in a website.

You need to create a web form with a file field and a view to process the upload.